# Как в разных экшенах использовать разные макеты?

Tags: php, yii

Есть небольшое приложение. Нужно чтобы при работе одного экшена использовался один макет при работе другого другой. Например для экшена index макет site.php для create main.php. Это нужно для того, чтобы клиентская и админская части имели разные внешние виды. Как это сделать?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в теле action'a, перед вызовом функции рендеринга, вставить вот это:

```
$this->layout = '//layouts/Ваш layout';
```

Answer (score 3):

Если вы собрались делать админку, то рекомендую сделать ее в отдельном [модуле](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebModule/), ему можно задать общий layout через одноименное свойство

```
<?php
class AdminModule extends CWebModule {
    //...
    protected $layout = '//layouts/admin';
    //...
}
```

Если вы все таки решите сделать это с помощью единого контроллера (что я вам настоятельно НЕ рекомендую), то достаточно будет указать layout в определении этого контроллера:

```
<?php
class AdminController extends Controller{
    //...
    protected $layout = '//layouts/admin';
    //...
}
```

Ну и последний вариант, только для одного action-а, вам уже описал [@Андрей Толмачевский](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/14011/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: Чем же все-таки плох AdminController?

Comment: @z_coder, для админки 100% понадобятся дополнительные методы для моделей, в том числе и afterFind, beforeSave, beforeDelete, которые не нужны (не допустимы) в работе сервиса вне админки, и тогда придется либо выносить функционал не в ОRМ-модели, а создавать доп.класс для работы админки, либо осуществлять проверки контроллера (сам понимаю, что написал бред :)) либо городить еще какие-то костыли, которые мне сейчас не пришли в залитую кофеином голову)

Comment: @z-coder, Еще, что существенно, лично у меня админка и  сами сервисы работают с различными пользователями СУБД, естествено, с разными правами, это, в принципе, можно реализировать и в контроллере, но, извините за выражение "быдлокода" прибавится при таком подходе

Comment: Спасибо буду иметь в виду.